# Related Rates - Calculus

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to figure out this problem for awhile now and I can't seem to find anything that actually helps. I found somewhat similar questions, but portions are missing, therefore it leaves me a bit confused. Here is the actual question:

> Suppose $xy=−4$ and $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}=2$. Find $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}$ when $x=4$.
>
> $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} =$ ?

Do you start by doing the following?: $-4y=-3$ to get $y = \frac{3}{4}$?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x\frac{dy}{dt}+y\frac{dx}{dt}=0$$

Now, put the values and calculate.

Here, $xy=-4$, $x=4$, hence, $y=-1$, $\frac {dy}{dt}=2$

Puttting this values we have,$$4\times 2+(-1)\times\frac {dx}{dt}=0\\\implies\frac {dx}{dt}=8$$

Comment: Thanks again. I literally spent forever on this since it was never covered.

Comment: I did. It telling me once I have 15 reputation points it will become public.